# Loop compares values in a column and inserts new row if different but ignores the first row if it's a unique value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I'm sorting an inventory page and separating the sizes after it's sorted to make it easier to read.

If the top row has a unique value (there's just one line of that item) then it wont insert a row after it and instead groups it with the next group of values.

If there's more than 1 row with that top value then it inserts a row properly after that group.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' sort by size then length
With ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Selection.Columns(3), Order:=xlDescending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Selection.Columns(4), Order:=xlDescending
    .SetRange Selection
    .Apply
End With


' insert rows between sizes
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
Dim oRng As Range

Set oRng = Range("D9")

iRow = oRng.Row
iCol = oRng.Column

Do
If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
   Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert shift = xlDown
   iRow = iRow + 2
Else
   iRow = iRow + 1
End If

Loop While Not Cells(iRow, iCol).Text = ""

End Sub
```

It ends up looking like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr3Rq.png

How do I get it to insert a row after that top value?

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify the approach slightly.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim oRng As Range

Set oRng = Range("D9", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For iRow = oRng.Count To 2 Step -1
    If oRng.Cells(iRow) <> oRng.Cells(iRow - 1) Then
        oRng.Cells(iRow).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    End If
Next iRow

End Sub
```

Comment: This is much more elegant and easier to read out. It also forced me to see that at some point during my experiments with tables I moved everything down a row so my data actually starts on D8, which resulted in my original problem. Thanks for helping me with this.